# IdentityServer4 version 3.1.4 redirect back to client after login only works with Firefox

Tags: redirect, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer4 version 3.1.4 with .NET Core 3.1 hosted on Internet Information Service 10.

Everything worked fine until the latest update for Edge, Chrome, and other browsers.

Now IdentityServer4 only redirects to client page after user login when I am using Firefox. Edge, Chrome, or others, return 302 code and go back to the IdentityServer4 user login page.

I read that it was due to the new cookie policy that Edge and Chrome enforce in their latest update.

I tried many solutions without success:

- Set level of security headers
- Enable Cors ...

Has anyone had the same problem? Did you manage to fix it?

Any idea is welcome

Please excuse my poor English

Answer (score 0):

Do make sure you have set the SameSite cookie attributes to the correct values. Otherwise the cookies might be lost in the interaction between the client and IdentityServer. They should usually be set correctly in the code.

Do use a tool like Fiddler and inspect the requests to see if you loose any of the cookies on the way.

see this link about [samesite](http://%20https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html?highlight=samesite#authentication)

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: One of the solutions I tried, was use SameSiteCookiesServiceCollectionExtensions that change SiteMode depends on navigators, but this only solve an old bug for old versions of chrome. I also set "services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>" with: opciones.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified; opciones.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always; I tried with all options for SameSiteMode without succes.Something I'm missing...I will be back to investigate and monitor cookies more intensively. For version 3.1 "Cookie SameSite Mode" not exist

Comment: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.0/reference/options.html#authentication

Comment: try to look at the traffic in fiddler and see if and where you loose the cookies.